# How to add hyphens at the first empty line of a text file?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I'm trying to add three hyphens to the first empty line of a given text file, and am trying to use `sed` for this. My initial file (a MultiMarkdown file) looks something like this:

```
title: "Ch. 1: Unparticipated Causality"
author: Jonathan Greig
biblio-files: bibliography.bib
biblio-style: chicago-authordate
mainfont: Linux Libertine O
linestretch: 1.5
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=1in
citecolor: black
linkcolor: black

## Ch 1: Unparticipated Causality ##
```

In between `linkcolor: black` and `## Ch 1 ... ##`, I'm trying to append a few dashes (`---`). Not quite sure how to accomplish this---the following command hasn't given for me:

```
sed '/^$/a ---' Chapter1Rev4.md
```

Currently the result is "command a expects \ followed by text", and not sure how to add the backslash or how to escape the hyphens/dashes.

Answer (score 3):

```
{ sed -e/./b -es/$/---/\;q; cat; } <in >out
```

...will not only replace only the first empty line w/ three hypens, it will also instruct `sed` to `q`uit trying to read the input file as soon as the first empty line is found and simply `cat` the rest. If you are using GNU `sed` you'll want to use the `-u`nbufferred switch, though.

Comment: Why don't you let [sed do it alone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228952/38906)?

Comment: @cuonglm - because then it would continue to line-buffer input and scan every line against a regex. `cat` just copies I/o.

Comment: Hmm, really. I think my loop `-e:1 -en\;b1` just copy i/o, too. Where did regex scan come from?

Comment: @cuonglm - no. At the least it is still breaking input into `\n`ewline delimited sections, and so it is still performing at least that simple scan on input. `cat` requests a `read()` from the kernel and immediately copies all that is returned to a `write()`. The `sed` loop has to scan the `read()` bit and divide it on newlines before `write()` ing each section out *(though most `sed`'s buffer output by default, so it just splits it up and pastes it back together again)*.

Comment: @cuonglm - depending on your `sed`, though, you can get similar behavior with `r\ /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @mikeserv, on the first command I get "syntax error near unexpected token `Chapter1Rev4.md' when running `{ sed -e/./b -es/$/---/\;q; cat; } Chapter1Rev4.md`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed 's/^$/---/' Chapter1Rev4.md
```

to do this in all empty lines.  For doing it in the first, I would use `awk` like this:

```
cat Chapter1Rev4.md | awk '{ if ($0 == "") { n++; if (n<2) print "---"; else print $0 } else print $0}'
```

(or redirect output to new file with appended `> newfile`).

Comment: With GNU sed you can write `sed '0,/^$/{s/^$/---&/}' file` to replace *only* the first empty line.

Comment: +1 or even just `sed '0,/^$/ s//---/' file`

Comment: Thanks you two, I use `sed` a lot but never needed that.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^$/{
  s/$/---/
  t1
}' -e:1 -en\;b1 <file
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to miss the first empty line when it is outputted.

Comment: @JonAndrew: Maybe your empty line is not *empty*. It can contain invisible character like tabs, sapces.

Answer (score 0):

**with** `a` it would look like this:

```
sed '0,/^$/{
/^$/a \
---    
}' yourfilename
```

or, if you want to substitute instead of append:

```
sed '0,/^$/{s/^$/---/}' yourfilename
```

the sed scripts — for clarity

```
# from the first line through the first empty line
0,/^$/{
  # no \ needed here, just append it
  /^$/a ---
}
```

or

```
# from the first line through the first empty line
0,/^$/{
   # replace empty lines with `---'
   s/^$/---/
}
```

this works because the block's addresses limit it to a certain range (the first line throught the first empty newline), only at the line where the block closes will it's only command, `s/^$/---/`, get to do anything.

Comment: I get this when I run the second command, appending the line: 'bad flag in substitute command: '}''.

On the first, for substituting, I get this: 'unexpected EOF (pending }'s)'.

Comment: the second command being `sed '0,/^$/{s/^$/---/}' yourfilename`?

Comment: just found what you were talking about. It should be all good now!